# Make image within div responsive css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a image on `div`. The image is dynamic added via `CMS`.

```
<div class="banner_page">
       <img src="banner.jpg" />

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.banner_page{
   height: 200px !important;
   left: 50%;
   max-width: 1920px !important;
   top: 0;
   position: relative;
   margin-left: -993px;
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

Once I start squeezing the browser the image exceeds the horizontal bar and I need to scooll horizontally to view the image. How can I make it responsive?

Comment: A simple `width:100%;` should be enough on the image, no ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSS:

```
.banner_page img{
    width:100%;
}
```

This will restrict the `img` width to the same as that available for the parent element, `.banner_page_img`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TSV6p/)

Comment: Hm Yes, but in the mobile screen the image is squeezed too much and it loses it's quality. Can we handle it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.banner_page img { width: 100%; }` as then it'll fill it's parent

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to constrain proportions add this :

```
.banner_page img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```